# Input doesn't work after fresh install

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

Livecd works fine, but after rebooting USB and ethernet don't work. X server and Unity start normally, animation is working.

Numlock is on, but doesn't change state, mouse is not working and etc.

I try force irqpoll but it didn't help

```
Motherboard: asus p5ld2
CPU: Pentium D
Ram: 2gb
```

Comment: It seems to be a driver incompatibility. If I were you I would try to install again first. If it doesn't work try to upgrade all your drivers.

Comment: Vitor Abella, i installed linux mint 18 and all works fine